# Thread not starting - no prompt for user input (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, input

I'm implementing a simple messaging application using Python. I've defined a client `CClient` which instantiates a `CMsgGateway` and then begins a thread which asks the user for input (while 1). The client is as follows:

```
from msginterface import CMsgGateway

class CClient():

    def __init__(self):
        self.port = 2400
        self.msgGate = CMsgGateway(self.port)
        Thread(target=self.inputMsg).start()

    def inputMsg(self):
        while 1:
            msg = input("Enter message:")
            self.msgGate.sendMsg(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmdchat = CClient()
```

The message gateway listens for messages being received in a separate thread (while 1). This class is defined as:

```
from threading import Thread
import socket, struct, sys

class CMsgGateway():
    def __init__(self, port):  

        self.port = port
        print("Listening on port " + str(self.port) + ".\n")
        Thread(target=self.serve).start()

    def serve(self):
        while 1:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.sock.bind(("", self.port))
            self.sock.listen(1)   
            self.rcvMsg()

    def rcvMsg(self):
        serverSocket, info = self.sock.accept()
        while 1:
        try:            
            buf = bytearray(4000)
            view = memoryview(buf)
            bytes = serverSocket.recv_into(view, 4000)
            if bytes:
                stx = view[0]
                Size = view[1:3]
                bSize = Size.tobytes()
                nTuple = struct.unpack(">H", bSize)
                nSize = nTuple[0]
                message = view[0:3+nSize]
                messageString = message.tobytes().decode("utf-8").strip()
                print("Received message:\n\n" + messageString)
                sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                break
        except socket.timeout:
            break

    def sendMsg(self, msgToSend):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        host = socket.gethostname()
        self.sock.connect((host, self.port))
        self.sock.send(msgToSend.encode())
        self.sock.close()
```

When I run the program the thread within `CMsgGateway` begins, listening for messages. However, as far as I can tell the thread within `CClient`, the `inputMsg` method, does not begin (I see no prompt to enter input e.g. "Enter message" is not displayed).

Could someone please help me figure out what is wrong with this? Many thanks.

Comment: On the main thread you should wait for the CClient thread to finish instead of exiting, or simply you should execute stuff on the main thread instead of creating another thread.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick...is it because there is nothing else being executed in the main thread after that `inputMsg` thread is started?